# Change SharePoint 2013 server name

Tags: 2013, server

How can I update SharePoint 2013 Foundation server and web application name?
I tried with

```
stsadm -o renameserver -oldservername oldservername -newservername newservername
```

but IIS in 80 port doesn't run

## Rename-SPServer

When I run

```
Rename-SPServer -Identity "wfb1" -Name "WFE1"
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Run the Rename-SPServer with SharePoint Management Shell

Comment: When I run the Rename-SPServer with SharePoint Management Shell happened but IIS 80 port doesn't run.what should I do for IIS ?Don't cahange server name in IIS.

Comment: When I run the Rename-SPServer with SharePoint Management Shell WARNING: you may also need to update any altarnete access mappings refering to oldservername .what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Once you change the Server Name, after you have to update the AAM settings in

- Central admin ( Central Admin > Application management> Cofigure AAM).
- Update the server name with New Server Name.

You can change the Server Name using the PowerShell as well.

```
Rename-SPServer -Identity "wfb1" -Name "WFE1"
```

Check more [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607556.aspx).